# InfoPath 2013 Form & Capturing Email Address

Tags: 2013, document-library, infopath, error

Before I give up on InfoPath I am asking for help.  I created an InfoPath form with two textbox fields. The form will be connected to a sharepoint 2013 document library.  I am not sure if I have created the form or connected the fields in the proper way.  Here is how I did it...

**1. Used a form to create a sharepoint list (document library)**

**2. Create field #1 - I want the first field for the user to enter into textbox.**

This is how I did it: Added the textbox control and changed the properties (required field...etc)

**3. Created field #2 - I want the second field for the user to choose their name/email address from people and group control.**

This is how I did it: Added a people and group control and changed the properties (required field...etc)

**4. Added a "Submit" button - after selecting submit the form information will be entered into the sharepoint list (document library)**

This is how I did it:

- Added a Button control to the form and changed the properties (name of the button (submit)...etc.)
- Enabled the users to submit the form after they have filled it out by going to "Submit Options" in the Data Connection Wizard entering in the document library location and the file name that will allow the users to submit more than form without overwriting.
- Added an Action Rule to the button.  To close form when completed.
- Selecting Submit Options allowed me to add custom action to the page after the user submits the form. After select "Submit Options" - select "send form to a single destination" when I place the document library location.

***Not positive if all the previous steps are correct, but this is where everything seems to fall apart.  When I publish the form a receive a few errors.***

1. The email address appears in the document library with the exchange format (i.e.io#!/joesmith).  I want the actual email address to appear.  GetUserProfileByName is the route to take. But, how do you get it to work?
2. When information is entered into the textbox a big "X" appears in the box. What does that mean?

[image]

3. When the user clicks "Submit" more errors appear.  Error #1 - the form already exists.  So, it needs a unique filename (I am assuming is the error), but I believe I identified the unique formula when I used the Data Connection Wizard.

Formula: concat("Form"username)

The question is... is there anything missing and where am I going wrong? Can anyone assist me or share any documentation that supports how to create and connect an InfoPath 2013 form to a sharepoint 2013 document library.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. The email address is not part of the person field. You will need to use a data connection to GetUserProfileByName to get the email address. Clayton Cobb wrote the ultimate tutorial here: http://claytoncobb.wordpress.com/2009/06/21/userprofileservice-extended/
2. No idea. A screenshot would be helpful.
3. What is the exact formula that you used to create a unique file name?

You are asking many questions in this one. It may be easier to break these down into the individual issues. InfoPath has a learning curve. It's very powerful but not very intuitive.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  You are right. InfoPath has learning huge learning curve. To answer your questions, I have edited the original questions with the screen shot and formula.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For Item #2 in the above question I found that when setting up the text box properties we checked multi line then this removed the Big X from the field once we published the form.  Without it and having the text box larger than 1 line the Big X would show up.